# Is there a limit to the number of UDP sockets, that can be used at a time?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

I need to use a lot of UDP Sockets pointing to different UDP ports for Receive function. Hence I have opened a lot of sockets and have used **BeginReceive()**  to call the respective callback function when a frame arrives in the particular ports.

Is there a limit to the number of sockets that I can keep open, at a time?

Thank You

Comment: I would imagine that the answer depends on your OS' limitations

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there's always limits:

- Amount of available ports. The absolute maximum would be 65535, but the true maximum is much more limited.
- Amount of available memory to handle the state for each of the sockets.
- Amount of memory for the receive buffers.

You'll find more examples, of course. But the port number limit *is* an absolute hard limit. Well, as long as you only have one IP address, of course. Nothing prevents you from having a few different network cards in your computer, or VPNs for example...

The more important question is "why?". UDP is message-based - it's actually quite easy to handle messages from thousands (and more) clients with just a single socket. Unlike TCP, UDP doesn't have any exclusive connections.